# A server that handles clients in the background while you can still type in commands

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I have been trying to make a server where multiple people can connect but i keep getting stuck on one problem. Allowing the server to listen to a client while the server host is still able to type in commands.

```
running = True

while running:
    command = input('>> ') # Allow for inputs but still connect new users (ex, a minecraft server)

    conn, addr = self.server.accept()
    print(f"[NEW CONNECTION] {conn}:{addr}")

    thread = threading.Thread(target=self.clientThread, args=(conn, addr))
    thread.start()
```

In short it listens for new connections or allows inputs but it never does both... I know i can do this by running it in different cmd's but it would be way better to keep it all in one place.

Comment: Simply move the `accept()` loop to a different thread than the `input()` loop. You are already familiar with that concept, since you are handling each connected client in its own thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could create a ClientHandler or create two methods. smth like this:

```
def connecting_users():
    # accept connections
    thread = threading.Thread(target=server_commands,)
    thread.start()
    while True:
          conn, addr = server.accept()
          # do your stuff

def server_commands():
    while True:
          command = input......
```

Note that this is not tested

Comment: Ah thanks, I tried it the other way around by putting the listening in another thread which did not work but for some reason this kinda works. I think I know something that may fully work...

Comment: Great! lmk if there are any issues ;)